# Content in TOC not printed during first compilation: due to Subfiles package?

Tags: table-of-contents, compiling

I am writing a report consisting of 3 separate files, each include a self-contained mathematical text. I work with the *subfiles* package. I have created three chapters in 3 separate files and included then in a main file like this:

```
\usepackage{subfiles}

\title{My Report}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\begin{document}

\chapter{Ch1}
\subfile{chapter1}
\chapter{Ch2}
\subfile{chapter2}
\chapter{Ch3}
\subfile{chapter3}

\end{document}
```

However, when I compile the file I gest an empty table of contents. How to create a table of contents which include the 3 chapters and their sections and subsections?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you run the complitation on the main file twice - the `\tableofcontents` picks up information written to a `.toc` file that is first written near the end of the first run.

Comment: Thank you. After compiling twice the content of the table of contents appears and in not empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing specifically to with the `subfiles` package.  The problem is caused by how LaTeX creates the table of contents.  In short you need to compile the main file twice in order to see the table of contents.

The reason for this is that on the each run LaTeX writes information about section headings to a separate file, with extension `.toc`.  On subsequent runs, provided you issue `\tableofcontenst` it reads the information from the `.toc` file in order to typeset of the table of contents.  On the first run, the `.toc` has not yet been created, and so no table of contents is printed.

Note that you may need to compile further times to get the correct page number reference in the table of contents.